# SimpleModal Dialoglo

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm using right now the SimpleModal Dialog box by Eric Martin. I found it simple, very easy to use and fits most of today layout.

My only concern is, how would I set an attribute for positioning that starts at the right side. i.e: `right: 0;`

The defaults are:

```
position: ["10%","70%"] ( which is Top, Left )
```

I'm actually using this into buttons and I would have the need to use the right positioning eventually.

What can I do to have the option of setting right as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS top, left or right. It's easy way